# Arranging tab items in tab header panel with dropdownlist

Tags: wpf, header, panel, tabcontrol, controltemplate

My requirement is to have a tab control with tab items of max width  180 pixels and  to shrink the tab item size to utmost 60 pixels, if the tabs doesn't fit in the window. Also to show a dropdown list with tab headers, if the tabs does not fit in the window size. As per my limited knowledge i feel i need to create a custom control that extends panel, say SqueezeTabPanel : Panel and to override the
MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods to calculate the with of each tabitems depending on the window size.

But I am not sure how to add the requirement of dropdown on top of this. As of now I have created a control template for the squeeze panel

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl" x:Key="SqueezeTabPanel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"  SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                      ClipToBounds="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <customControl:SqueezeTabPanel
                    x:Name="HeaderPanel"  Panel.ZIndex ="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"  Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0" Margin="8,0,4,-1" IsItemsHost="true" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel"
                        Background="{StaticResource PrimaryTextBoxColor}"
                        BorderThickness= "1" CornerRadius="2"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                        <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        Margin="4"
                        ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource SecondarySmallText}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ToolTip >
                        <ToolTip Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" x:Name ="TabToolTip"/>
                        </ToolTip>

                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                    <Border  Name="Border" Margin="0,0,-4,4"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                          CornerRadius="0,5,0,0" Height="24">
                      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"  VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                             ContentSource="Header"   Margin="12,2,12,2"   RecognizesAccessKey="True" Height="20"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTabItemBackground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryTextColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBackground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledTextColor}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledTextColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And my custom control for SqueezeTabPanel is

```
public class SqueezeTabPanel : Panel
{

    private double _rowHeight;
    private double _scaleFactor;

    // Ensure tabbing works correctly
    static SqueezeTabPanel()
    {
        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SqueezeTabPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(KeyboardNavigationMode.Once));
        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SqueezeTabPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle));
    }

    // This Panel lays its children out horizontally.
    // If all children cannot fit in the allocated space,
    // the available space is divided proportionally between them.
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        // See how much room the children want
        double minwidthrequired = 60;
        double width = 0.0;
        this._rowHeight = 0.0;
        foreach (UIElement element in this.Children)
        {
            element.Measure(availableSize);
            Size size = this.GetDesiredSizeLessMargin(element);
            this._rowHeight = Math.Max(this._rowHeight, size.Height);
            width += size.Width;
        }

        // If not enough room, scale the
        // children to the available width
        if (width > availableSize.Width)
        {
            this._scaleFactor = availableSize.Width / width;
            width = 0.0;
            foreach (UIElement element in this.Children)
            {
                double itemWidth = element.DesiredSize.Width * this._scaleFactor;
                if (itemWidth>=60)
                    element.Measure(new Size(itemWidth, availableSize.Height));
                else
                    element.Measure(new Size(minwidthrequired, availableSize.Height));
                width += element.DesiredSize.Width;
            }

        }
         else
            this._scaleFactor = 1.0;

        return new Size(width, this._rowHeight);
    }

    // Perform arranging of children based on the final size
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        foreach (UIElement element in this.Children)
        {
            Size size1 = element.DesiredSize;
            Size size2 = this.GetDesiredSizeLessMargin(element);
            Thickness margin = (Thickness)element.GetValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty);
            double width = size2.Width;
            if (element.DesiredSize.Width != size2.Width)
                width = arrangeSize.Width - point.X; 
            element.Arrange(new Rect(
                point,
                new Size(Math.Min(width, size2.Width), this._rowHeight)));
            double leftRightMargin = Math.Max(0.0, -(margin.Left + margin.Right));
            point.X += size1.Width + (leftRightMargin * this._scaleFactor);
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }

    // Return element's size
    // after subtracting margin
    private Size GetDesiredSizeLessMargin(UIElement element)
    {
        Thickness margin = (Thickness)element.GetValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty);
        Size size = new Size();
        size.Height = Math.Max(0.0, element.DesiredSize.Height - (margin.Top + margin.Bottom));
        size.Width = Math.Max(0.0, element.DesiredSize.Width - (margin.Left + margin.Right));
        return size;
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not. Please help by giving a right direction. Thanks in advance